# My Setting icon is not showing in project window

Tags: android

My Setting icon is not showing in project window of Android Studio.

anybody know what's the reason

the setting icon there is missing after updating

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Access the project setting by clicking 'File' on the left hand corner. It'll be one of the options in the overflow that appears.